# ActionCable - private chatrooms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I created a chat with ActionCable: there's a general, public chat and option of direct messages. Now I'd like to implement private chatrooms (like Slack's ones). Only difference between direct message and private chatroom is the first one being between only 2 people, and second one obviously 2 and more, with option to add new poeple or to "delete" someone.
Creating private messages was quite easy. I have PrivateMessagesController with one action - show. When user clicks on other user's name, conversation starts.
In my show.html.erb where I have users' usernames being displayed as links:

```
<%= link_to user.email, direct_message_path(user.id), data:
{behavior: "chatroom-link", chatroom_id:
Chatroom.direct_chat([current_user, user]).id } %>
```

The path to the conversation is

```
http://localhost:3000/direct_messages/3
```

where "3" is other user's id. 
I can't figure out what `id` should I pass to my

```
http://localhost:3000/private_chatrooms/id
```

I have ordinary form for creating new Chatroom. I added `visibility` column to my `Chatroom` model - it's string, `'public'` or `'private'`. So while creating new `Chatroom` I provide its name, choose its kind(visibility) and I also have list of users with checkboxes. But ids of users are in `params[:user_ids]` (coming from checkbox_tag) only for `create` action, then I lose it. 
What's more, I need to be able to add people after creating the chatroom. 
I thought adding private chatrooms wouldn't be very different from creating private messages (difference is theoretically only in the quantity of participants) but I'm really running in circles.